# EasyMock tests failing with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$2 on Java 17

Tags: easymock, java-17

Since upgradting to Java 17 my unit test that are using EasyMock are failing with to the following exception

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$2     at
> org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory.createEnhancer(ClassProxyFactory.java:233)
> at
> org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory.createProxy(ClassProxyFactory.java:165)
> at
> org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:107)
> at
> org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:80)
> at org.easymock.EasyMockSupport.mock(EasyMockSupport.java:77)   at
> org.easymock.EasyMockSupport.createMock(EasyMockSupport.java:364)

I am running the tests using maven-surefire-plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** as of [EasyMock 5.0.0](http://blog.tremblay.pro/2022/10/easymock-500-is-out.html) `add-opens` is not required anymore.

Issues [#274](https://github.com/easymock/easymock/issues/274) and [#300](https://github.com/easymock/easymock/pull/300) have been resolved with version 5.0.0.

So upgrading to EasyMock version 5 solves the issue.

---

Java 17 contains [JEP 403 which strongly encapsulates JDK Internals](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/403).

As EasyMock uses some of these internal APIs access to these need to be made accessable by setting the command line option `add-opens`

> If you have to allow code on the class path to do deep reflection to
> access nonpublic members, then use the --add-opens runtime option.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm

As pointed out in [this EasyMock issue](https://github.com/easymock/easymock/issues/274)

> you need to open that package in command line

So to fix the exception `add-opens` needs to be set as [`argLine`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine) for the maven-surefire-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <configuration>
        <argLine>
            --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
        </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The answer is correct. I still need to release a full Java 17 support. Code is almost ready but any help is appreciated.